# AWS CDK Batch - Job Definitions platform capabilities

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am updating a FARGATE spot batch jobs to use the newer L2 constructs and I am running into the error,

```
An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the SubmitJob operation: Job Queue is attached to Compute Environment that can not run Jobs with capability EC2.
```

Previously, I defined a job definition, and set `platform_capabilities=["FARGATE"]`,

```
job_definition = batch.CfnJobDefinition(
    self,
    "myJobDefinition",
    # details omitted
    platform_capabilities=["FARGATE"],
)
```

I am trying to attach a job definition to a fargate spot compute env,

```
compute_env = batch.FargateComputeEnvironment(self, "spotEnv",
    vpc=vpc,
    spot=True
)
queue = batch.JobQueue(self, "JobQueue", priority=10)
queue.add_compute_environment(compute_env, 1)
```

However, I am not seeing any parameters for `platform_capabilities` with `batch.EcsJobDefinition`

Comment: I fix this by changing `contaier=EcsEc2ContainerDefinition` to `container=EcsFargateContainerDefinition` in my `EcsJobDefinition`